# Is it possible to open Windows Explorer from a linklabel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

Good Morning All,

I have a project which will be distributed as an Excel add-in, it is written in C# and uses ExcelDNA.

What I would like to do is add a linklabel to my add-in main form, when clicked, I would like this to open windows explorer at a specific index, e.g. the G: drive.

Is this possible? I've seen some examples but haven't been able to wrangle them,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely:

From the [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853):

```
   Option            Function
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------   
   /n                Opens a new single-pane window for the default
                     selection. This is usually the root of the drive that
                     Windows is installed on. If the window is already
                     open, a duplicate opens.

   /e                Opens Windows Explorer in its default view.

   /root,<object>    Opens a window view of the specified object.

   /select,<object>  Opens a window view with the specified folder, file,
                     or program selected.

   Examples
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Example 1: Explorer /select,C:\TestDir\TestProg.exe
              Opens a window view with TestProg selected.

   Example 2: Explorer /e,/root,C:\TestDir\TestProg.exe
              Opens Explorer with drive C expanded and TestProg selected.

   Example 3: Explorer /root,\\TestSvr\TestShare
              Opens a window view of the specified share.

   Example 4: Explorer /root,\\TestSvr\TestShare,select,TestProg.exe
              Opens a window view of the specified share with TestProg selected.
```

So you can call `Explorer /select,G:\yourfile` to open the explorer with that file/directory selected.

Put that call in [`Process.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) et voila :)